# Confusing option on the LQ queue dialog for commentary

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

In the dialog that lets you select a comment while recommending deletion for an answer, the choice for "this should be a comment" is confusing:

[image: Choice for "this should be a comment]

The current option (bold text) reads:

> **This is commentary on another post, not an answer**

It's very confusing what "other post" this option is referring to. The non-bold text does a much better job of explaining what the option is.

To be more clear, this option should be changed to:

> **This is commentary on the question, not an answer**

so that it's more clear which post this option is referring to.

Answer (score 12):

That would be a horrible change. There are people who post new answers as commentary on *another answer* and not the question. Questions and answers are both considered posts, so the option correctly covers both of those options.